# Using a session wrapper for replacing direct call to session variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I use a session wrapper like this:

```
public interface ISessionWrapper
{
   // ...
   CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
}

public class SessionWrapper: ISessionWrapper
{
    private T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void SetInSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    // ...

    public CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get { return GetFromSession<CultureInfo>("Culture"); }
        set { SetInSession("Culture", value); }
    }
}
```

I can use this interface in my controller like this:

```
private readonly ISessionWrapper sessionWrapper = new SessionWrapper();
// ...
ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
sessionWrapper.Culture = ci;
```

**But how can I access this wrapper in the view below to replace the (direct call to) session variable?**

```
@switch (Session["Culture"].ToString()) 
{    
    case "fr":  
        // ...

    case "uk":  
        // ...
}
```

Comment: You can create a HTMLHelper extension where you will use the session wrapper...

Comment: @sajoshi: you are right. I'm so stupid :( (learning MVC)

Comment: Close this one then.. and may be +1 for the comment..

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the base view:

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual ISessionWrapper SessionWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return new SessionWrapper();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual ISessionWrapper SessionWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return new SessionWrapper();
        }
    }
}
```

your views will have access to SessionWrapper property.

Make sure to add pageBaseType="SessionWrapper" attribute to pages tag in web.config.